# Nested Models in Serializer django

Tags: django, serialization, filter, django-rest-framework, model

I cannot get the last measurement for each device based on the device's ID from the measurement. If someone can advise me on how to implement this?

**Models**

```
class Devices(models.Model):
                        deviceid = models.AutoField(db_column='deviceId', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
                        devicename = models.CharField(db_column='deviceName', unique=True, max_length=128)  # Field name made lowercase
                        devicestatus = models.IntegerField(db_column='deviceStatus')  # Field name made lowercase.
                    
                        Class Meta:
                            managed = False
                            db_table = 'devices'
                    
class Measurements(models.Model):
                        measurementid = models.AutoField(db_column='measurementId', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
                        deviceid = models.ForeignKey(Devices,   models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="measurment_details", db_column='deviceId')  # Field name made lowercase.
                        measurement = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
                        
                    
                        class Meta:
                            managed = False
                            get_latest_by = 'measurementtime'
                            db_table = 'measurements'
```

**Serializer**

```
class MeasurmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Measurements
      fields = ('measurementid','measurement')
   
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  latestmeasurment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  count = 0 
 
  
  def get_latestmeasurment(self, obj):
       qs = Measurements.objects.using('@@@').last()
       serializer = MeasurmentsSerializer(instance=qs, many=False)
       self.count = 1 + self.count
       print(self.count , serializer.data )
       return serializer.data
 
  class Meta:
    model = Devices
    fields = ("devicename", 'latestmeasurment')
```

**Views**

```
class RetrieveAllDevicesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  http_method_names = ['get']
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
  serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
  queryset = Devices.objects.using('@@@')
```

**In serializer, you can see the count for primitive debug:**

```
1 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
2 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
3 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
4 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
5 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
6 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
7 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
8 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
9 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
10 {'measurementid': 2942080, 'measurement': '35.0'}
```

**Response in JSON from view:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWjaj.png)

Comment: I think part of the issue might be the fact that are not a "created at" date in the measurement model, if it were not unmanaged, I would advice to use a field `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this table was not created by me. The main thing is that measurement tables has a lot of rows and I would like to retrieve just the last one for each device as you see in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_latestmeasurment(self, obj):
    device_measurements = obj.measurment_details.all()
    last_measurement = device_measurements.order_by('id').last()
    serializer = MeasurmentsSerializer(last_measurement)
    return serializer.data
```

you get all measurments for each device and after sorting it you'll get the last one as your last_measurment

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me not the last but the first measurement parameter.

Comment: If you replace last() by first() does that happen too? Maybe the thing is reversed

Comment: OMG. thanks !!! it helped :) the problem was from my side instead of using measurement id I used device id which is not right.

Comment: The last question is how I can improve the time request in the following case  `obj.measurment_details.all()` are taking all objects which is quite long, thanks!!!!

Comment: @titarch `obj.measurment_details.all()` is getting all rows from object so done following based on your response `def get_latestmeasurment(self, obj):
    device_measurements = obj.measurment_details.all()
    serializer = MeasurmentsSerializer(device_measurements)
    return serializer.data`
It does the same, but instead of all rows from the object, it gives me just the last one. Can you update your answer? I am not able to make any changes :), also can you advise how I can improve the time request right now is between 14-17 sec which is quite long

Comment: @Denis I cannot update this answer as I didn't write it. As for making it faster you can probably use `prefetch_related` in your view: `queryset = Devices.objects.using('@@@').prefetch_related("measurment_details")`

Comment: @titarch, unfortunately, it doesn't work because it takes indifinite time to respond.

Comment: @Denis there must be a huge amount of measurements then. What is the type of database used? I know I had better performance after running an "ANALYZE" command once that optimised things with some reindexing

Comment: @titarch type is Relational database, can you please explain more detail on how you sort this problem in your experience, Thanks :)

Comment: @titarch, and yes is quite a lot, you can see by  measurementsid  is 2942080 at the moment, It needs to be rebuilt but have trouble in how to sort all staff